# Jquery .click() for headings not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I have a problem. In one of my projects, I want to include a slideToggle function for a panel, on the click of a heading. I basically want this.

https://jsfiddle.net/abrch86f/

The problem is, when I click on the heading, (an h3), nothing happens, and to check, I added an alert message in the click function as well. I basically am looking for common mistakes that would make this happen. JQuery is definetely loaded in, I always use an alert message on document load to check. Here is my code

JQuery

```
$('h3').click(function(){
  alert("It works!");
  $('.content').slideToggle();
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="left-panel">
 <h3>Hire Soldiers</h3>

            <div class="content">
            <button onClick="hireSwordsman()">Swordsman - Cost 70 Ore</button>
            <button onClick="hireVanguard()">Vanguard - Cost 90 Ore</button>
            <button onClick="hireBowman()">Bowman - Cost 125 Ore</button>
            <button onClick="hireKnight()">Knight - Cost 200 Ore</button>
            </div>
      </div>
```

The reason I included my left panel div is because I'm not sure if z-index has to do with it, but I have a hunch. Could display be an issue? I don't know why it would because I didn't change it at all. Again, I stress that I'm just looking for things that would cause it to not work. If you think you can directly help me and need more info, just ask.

Thanks!

Comment: z-index will definitely cause that to happen. If some other elements are covering `h3` element you intend to click, the element that is covering `h3` up will register the click event instead.

If you replace the HTML in the fiddle you have with your HTML in this question and change the `$.slideToggle()` selector to `.content`, it should work perfectly fine.

Comment: Btw, a good way of checking for what is actually being clicked on when experiencing these kinds of problems, is to do this right after the `ready()`:
 `$(document).click(function(e){
   console.log(e.target);
  });` 
However, this logs EVERYTHING you click on, so comment it out or remove it when it's not needed.

Comment: Wow @junkfoodjunkie this is actually SUPER useful! Now I was able to determine that something was blocking my h3. Thanks!

Comment: Also, since you're already using jQuery, you should get rid of those `onClick()` calls in the HTML, and just bind that in the JS-file instead.

Comment: Yes I was getting around to that eventually... just didn't finish that yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that my h3 I was targeting to click, was covered up by another div. Thanks for the explanation by @josephting I needed to adjust my z-index to be higher like this:

```
h3 {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

A good way to check if your elements are blocked by something else is by using this function explained by @junkfoodjunkie that prints to the console log what element you clicked.

```
$(document).click(function(e){ console.log(e.target); });
```

So, by adding that declaration to my CSS, my problem was fixed. Remember that if you have used higher z-index values before, you might have to raise them according to what your heading is in front of.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need. Please let me know if this works for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('h3').click(function(){
  $('.content').slideToggle();
});
});
```

```css
.content{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left-panel">
 <h3>Hire Soldiers</h3>

            <div class="content">
            <button onClick="hireSwordsman()">Swordsman - Cost 70 Ore</button>
            <button onClick="hireVanguard()">Vanguard - Cost 90 Ore</button>
            <button onClick="hireBowman()">Bowman - Cost 125 Ore</button>
            <button onClick="hireKnight()">Knight - Cost 200 Ore</button>
            </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: This wouldn't have fixed my problem, because my h3 was covered up, It is a good idea to use document.ready() though. Thanks!

Comment: Sharing a little love this thanksgiving season, it won't show up publicly though, because I don't have 15 rep yet